# select value of dropdownlist item jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drop-down-menu

**HTML**

```
<select id="selectDepartment">
  <option value="1">120</option>
  <option value="2">20</option>
  <option value="3">140</option>
  <option value="4">4120</option>
  <option value="5">560</option>
  <option value="6">451</option>
  <option value="7">310</option>
  <option value="8">656</option>
  <option value="9">444</option>
  <option value="10">555</option>
  <option value="11">2560</option>
  <option value="12">450</option>
</select>
```

**jQuery**

```
$("#selectDepartment").change( function() {

alert($("select option:selected").val()); 

});
```

the above function always shows value **1** on alert, when I select any one of the options

Comment: Try changing `$("select option:selected")` to `$("option:selected", this)`.  `$("select option:selected")` will grab the 1st select on the page, which may not be the one you want.

Comment: See: http://jsfiddle.net/Rdh3Q/ ... seems to work fine..

Comment: @MarcoJohannesen: Try [this version](http://jsfiddle.net/Rdh3Q/1/).

Comment: @BradChristie ... Dosen't change that his posted code works. Obviously he needs something different if he got more selectboxes, like the answer you posted. But his code is still "working" considering his HTML.

Comment: @MarcoJohannesen: "Working" is a relative term as are the metrics which are used to measure. I could say my car with no tires or engine is "working" because it rolls down the road, however other drivers may be inclined to disagree.

Comment: Hehe true! Just pointing out that he should think twice when creating the thread, and include ALL source that's relevant, because in this instance for example the error isn't reproduces in the code posted (you guys still fixed it ofcourse). That's why people should always reproduce it in pages like JsFiddle :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your method of finding the selection option is vague. You're saying "Grab all `<select>`s". You then go on to grab the `:select`ed option from each of them (of all `<select>`s on the page). Continued, `.val()` takes the first value off the top.

Simply put, you're always fetching the selected value of the *first* `<select>` found on the page. Assuming `#selectDepartment` isn't the first `<select>`, your value will never change.

Try to keep the scope to within the current `<Select>` using `this`:

```
$('#selectDepartment').change(function(){
  var selopt = $('option:selected',this);
});
```

Note that I specify the scope to within the `<select>` that triggered the `.change()`. Also note this really isn't necessary as `val()` works just as easily:

```
var selopt = $(this).val();
```

Let jQuery do the heavy lifting. You really only need `option:selected` if you want control over styling that specific element, or you're working with a multi-select and want more control.

Comment: Just to add, `.text()` will give you the text of the selected option.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
$("#selectDepartment").change( function() {

     var selected = $(this).find(":selected");

});
```